# Istream::get считывает на один байт больше

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь побайтово считать текстовый файл и вывести его содержимое на экран. Вот программа:

```
std::ifstream inp;
inp.open("inp.txt", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<std::pair<char,unsigned int>> vect;
while(!inp.eof())
{
    char ch;
    inp.get(ch);
    std::cout << ch;
}
std::cout << "\n";
inp.close();
```

Проблема в том, что последний символ в файле выводится на один раз больше, чем нужно. Например, если файл содержит слово

```
qwerty
```

То на выходе программы будет

```
qwertyy
```

Comment: Если Вы пишете код в студии (то есть под Window), то открывать в бинарном режиме файл (`std::ios::binary`) не совсем по феншую.

Comment: А что там не фэншуйного?

Comment: После .get(), перед печатью, добавьте проверку на .eof()

Comment: если файл текстовый, открывайте его как текст (`std::ifstream::in`). Дело в том, что в бинарном режиме под виндой у текстовых файлов перевод строки кодируется двумя байтами. Почему так? винда. Под линуксом таких проблем нет.

Comment: Хм. Вообще говоря, у меня там необязательно текст, это может быть любой файл, мне нужно не текст, а тупо последовательность байтов. Но за инфу спасибо.

Comment: @KoVadim, в ubuntu g++ такая же ерунда

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tttx.cpp
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ echo -n qwerty >inp.txt
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    qwertyy
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

а вот

    if (!inp.eof())
      std::cout << ch;


решает проблему. 

И дело здесь не в винде, а в плохо спроектированном IO в крестах.

Comment: Нормально io спроектировано. Оно плохо работает, если его применять криво. Оно спроектировано, что бы писать код в стиле

    char ch;
    while((ch = inp.get()) != EOF) {
        std::cout << ch;
    }

и работает отлично.

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы серьезно считаете столь разное поведение переопределенных методов

     ch = inp.get()

и 

     inp.get(ch)

отличным проектным решением?

--

Кстати, код 

     char ch;
     while ((ch = inp.get()) != EOF) ....

с произвольными файлами будет работать неправильно, например, в винде до первой русской буквы `я` (код 0xff).

Answer (score 2):

Исправленная программа будет такой

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream inp;
    inp.open("inp.txt", std::ios::in);
    int ch;
    while((ch = inp.get()) != EOF)
    {
        std::cout << (char)ch;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    inp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

*подправил немного по рекомендации [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp),  что бы оно под виндами работало*

а теперь ответы:

**Q:** Почему последний символ читался дважды?

**A:** А потому, что get проверил, что конец файла и не сдвигал указатель.

**Q:** Почему IO так криво спроектировано?

**A:** Оно криво с точки зрения программистов java подобных. А с точки зрения С - очень удобно.

**Q:** Почему проверка на eof не срабатывает в оригинальном варианте?

**A:** А потому что эта проверка - это просто проверка внутренней переменной-флажка (одного бита). Можно хоть сто раз проверять на eof - файл никто трогать не будет. А выставляют это флажок функции чтения.

**Q:** а почему не возвратить исключение?

**A:** достигнуть конец файла - это не исключительная ситуация. Это можно предвидеть многими способами (например, прочитать размер файла и считать нужное кол-во символов).

**Q:** а почему нужно текстовый файл открывать в текстовом режиме?

**A:** если Вы работаете под линукс/мак, то нет никаких проблем. Там в большинстве случаев это абсолютно эквивалентные режимы. Но вот под Windows есть проблема с переводом строк. Они кодируются двумя байтами ( в нормальных ОС - одним байтом). При чтении файла в текстовом режиме винда с runtime языка это дело прозрачно прячут. Также при чтении бинарных файлов в текстовом режиме (то есть наоборот) могут быть проблемы с чтением нулевых символов. И последний аргумент - это логично, открывать текстовый файл в текстовом режиме - это как бесплатный комментарий.

Comment: @KoVadim, поправьте, замените

    char ch;

на

    int ch;

и соответственно поправьте 

    std::cout << (char)ch;

.  См. мой коммент выше (под вопросом).


Думаю, теперь понятно, почему я считаю IO в крестах плохим? Таких штучек, провоцирующих ошибки в ней (и вообще в крестах) полно.

И обратите внимание, именно с т.з. Си (а не Java) программиста.

Comment: Не пишу я под винду.

Comment: И я не пишу.

    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ tttx.cpp
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ hd inp.txt
    00000000  71 77 ff 65 72 74 79 0a                            |qw.erty.|
    00000008
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
    qw
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$

Ньюлаын в конце появился после редактирования в emacs для вставки 0xff